# how i can find max price and company name

Tags: python, pandas

df_max = df.loc[df['price'].max(),['make','price']]

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
384                 try:
--> 385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
386                 except ValueError as err:

ValueError: 45400 is not in range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
7 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/range.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
385                     return self._range.index(new_key)
386                 except ValueError as err:
--> 387                     raise KeyError(key) from err
388             raise KeyError(key)
389         return super().get_loc(key, method=method, tolerance=tolerance)

KeyError: 45400.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to select the ***make*** and ***price*** from a row that has the highest price value.

```
df[['price', 'make']].loc[df.price == df.price.max()]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) is what you are trying to achieve.

```py
df_max = df.loc[df["price"] == df["price"].max(), ["make", "price"]]
```